# What is the best way to open a QWidget inside a QMainWindow made in Qt4 and python?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to be able to create (or open, i dont know the correct way to say it) a `QWidget` inside a `QMainWindow`. My main window contains only the status bar and upper toolbar. And for example i want to open the settings window, i dont want it to show on a different window i want it to show inside my main window.

I was looking for some examples but i wasnt able to implement it in my case. My gui is a file made by `QDesigner`.

Here is my example code:

```
import sys,os,time,logging
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic ,QtSql,QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, SIGNAL
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
sys.stderr = open("errlog.txt", "w")

class dialog1(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        file_path = os.path.abspath("ui/dialog1.ui")
        uic.loadUi(file_path, self)


class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        # super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        file_path = os.path.abspath("ui/main.ui")
        uic.loadUi(file_path, self)
        self.actionAbout.triggered.connect(self.run_dialog1)

    def run_dialog1(self):
        dialog = dialog1(parent=MyWindow)
        dialog.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I will apreciate if you could help me with this, so i can understand how it works. Thank you

**Update and solve:**

Thaks for the help guys, i solved the problem. I will provide an update.

```
import sys,os,time,logging
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic ,QtSql,QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread, SIGNAL
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import mysql.connector as mariadb
import base64
from uuid import getnode as get_mac
from platform import system as system_name # Returns the system/OS name
from os import system as system_call       # Execute a shell command
import subprocess
sys.stderr = open("errlog.txt", "w")

class settings(QtGui.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        QtGui.QTabWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        file_path = os.path.abspath("ui/settings.ui")
        uic.loadUi(file_path, self)

class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        # super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        file_path = os.path.abspath("ui/main.ui")
        uic.loadUi(file_path, self)

    def run_settings(self):
        self.form_widget = settings(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.form_widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What do you mean with inside the widget? You want it to be part of the widget, which is on top of the widget. You could show an image of what you want to get.

Comment: You could also provide .ui files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [setCentralWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget)
to add QWidget inside a QMainWindow,

If you want to switch between differant widgets inside the QMainWindow you can use the [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html) as a central widget, add your widgets like settings to the stackedWidget and add some buttons to switch between the widgets.

Comment: Thanks, i like your solution to. This ideea i implemented after i've read vedadev answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of something like a dock widget?
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html#details

> QDockWidget provides the concept of dock widgets, also know as tool palettes or utility windows. Dock windows are secondary windows placed in the dock widget area around the central widget in a QMainWindow.